# magento 1.9 error 404: page not found

Tags: magento, url-rewriting, magento-1.9

I've installed a plugin on my magento 'addThis' but when I'm going to the setting on the plugin, magento gives me an error 404 page not found. Later I saw that 
my admin url is: tienda.mabaonline.com/admin/admin/... but I don't know how to change this url I don't know why /admin is repeated, on my local.xml file it's only

```
<adminhtml>
            <args>
                <frontName><![CDATA[admin]]></frontName>
            </args>
</adminhtml>
```

Comment: make sure to refresh cache then logout and login of magento admin

Comment: O, yes, I didn't clean the cache, thanks -.-''

Answer (score 1):

I'm just to clean the cache -.-'' so there isn't any problem